# Dynamic base menu: php or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, menu

I'm redoing my portfolio website, and I not sure which way to go about it; jQuery or PHP? combination? My goal is to allow myself to drop any html/php file into a folder label "projects". Then have the menu/main nav create links that match file's title in the header or something AND also have a custom class/label from something in the file (is this even possible?). Along with that have the links load there content(images and text) into the content area.

Illustration of what I'm trying to put into words->[Image](http://www.jordandravis.com/storage/img013.jpg)

Thanks in Advance

Jordan

Comment: Both. Make your site work with just PHP and then AJAXify it.

Comment: In short, PHP is required for what you are trying to do and it is possible for sure. Being as jQuery is a client side javascript library, you would be unable to interact with a servers file system. Once the DOM is loaded from the server, you will be able to manipulate it with jQuery.. You would need both.

Comment: So in short, PHP with some jQuery sprinkled on top. That's what I was thinking. But I wanted to make sure; my PHP/jQuery knowledge is very limited at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If You are just asking if this is possible... yes it is, using PHP to read the directory and files within it. You can use the `readdir()` function to read the files in the directory, then you could use PHP to build a JavaScript or jQuery based menu system.

There are other approaches as well. You could use AJAX + PHP to build the menu after the page loads. I think you need to narrow the scope of your question.